# jquery regular expression with custom messages

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need to implement a regular expression in my asp.net mvc(C#) application using jquery.

I have a sign in form, in which i need to validate the fields with the required and regular expression.

Putting more clearly, I have `Username` and `Password` fields in my Sign in form. I need to validate as required first, and if the user entered any value, then i need to validate with the regular expression.

For ex.: The `Username` must be minimum 5 characters and no special characters, if entered invalid values. it should say `Please enter a valid Username with atleast 5 characters and no special characters`.

The Password must be minimum 5 characters and atleast 1 special character, 1 numeric, if entered invalid value, it should say `Please enter a valid password with atleast 5 characters and should contain one numer and special character`

So i need to give custom messages for each of the fields for required and regular expression.

Is there and common plugin or function to use for regular expression in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a common straight forward method implementation in SO :

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
            regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        else if (regexp.global)
            regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input.");
```

It can be used as:

```
        $('#signinForm').validate({
            rules: {
                Username: {
                    required: true,
                    regex: "YOURREGULAREXPRESSION"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Username: {
                    required: "Enter the Username",
                    regex: "Enter the valid Username"
                }
            }
        });
```

Thus we can have as many custom validation(regex) with custom messages.

Answer (score 2):

Username:

`/^\w{5,}$/` Five or more word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and underscore)

Password:

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=_|\W).{5,}$/i` A string of at least five chars with minimum one digit, one alphabet (case insensitive) and one special character.

Comment: Why the `*` ? Isn't that zero or more? Shouldn't you use `+` for one or more? So, should that not be `/^(?=.+\d)(?=.+[a-z])(?=_|\W).{5,}$/i`

Answer (score 1):

You don't do regular expressions in jQuery. It's built into JavaScript itself. Of course, there are validation plugins for jQuery that utilize regular expressions.

Check out: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Most of those plugins should let you enter a custom message to display if it doesn't validate.